# Auto-gptq OSError - Win32

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytorch, large-language-model, autogpt

I have python 3.11.5, VS Code, Cuda 12.2 (but installed 11.7 to be certain), torch 2.0.1 with cuda 11.7, running on Windows 11. Can give more details if asked.

I used this wheel to install https://github.com/PanQiWei/AutoGPTQ/releases/download/v0.4.1/auto_gptq-0.4.2+cu117-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
and then `pip install auto_gptq-0.4.2+cu117-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl`

When I try to **`import auto_gptq`**, I get

**OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application**

From what I read, there is incompatabilty between 64bit and 32bit of some systems, but have tried everything, reinstalled every dependency and whatnot, but issue persists.

Below is the full trace of the error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 import auto_gptq

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\auto_gptq\__init__.py:4
      2 from .modeling import BaseQuantizeConfig
      3 from .modeling import AutoGPTQForCausalLM
----> 4 from .utils.peft_utils import get_gptq_peft_model
      5 from .utils.exllama_utils import exllama_set_max_input_length

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\auto_gptq\utils\peft_utils.py:9
      6 from typing import List, Optional
      8 import torch
----> 9 from peft import get_peft_model, PeftConfig, PeftModel, PeftType
     10 from peft.peft_model import PEFT_TYPE_TO_MODEL_MAPPING
     11 from peft.tuners.lora import LoraConfig, LoraLayer, LoraModel, Embedding

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\peft\__init__.py:22
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 # There's no way to ignore "F401 '...' imported but unused" warnings in this
      3 # module, but to preserve other warnings. So, don't check this module at all.
   (...)
     17 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     18 # limitations under the License.
     20 __version__ = "0.5.0"
---> 22 from .auto import (
     23     AutoPeftModel,
     24     AutoPeftModelForCausalLM,
     25     AutoPeftModelForSequenceClassification,
     26     AutoPeftModelForSeq2SeqLM,
     27     AutoPeftModelForTokenClassification,
     28     AutoPeftModelForQuestionAnswering,
     29     AutoPeftModelForFeatureExtraction,
     30 )
     31 from .mapping import (
     32     MODEL_TYPE_TO_PEFT_MODEL_MAPPING,
     33     PEFT_TYPE_TO_CONFIG_MAPPING,
   (...)
     36     inject_adapter_in_model,
     37 )
     38 from .peft_model import (
     39     PeftModel,
     40     PeftModelForCausalLM,
   (...)
     45     PeftModelForFeatureExtraction,
     46 )

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\peft\auto.py:31
     21 from transformers import (
     22     AutoModel,
     23     AutoModelForCausalLM,
   (...)
     27     AutoModelForTokenClassification,
     28 )
     30 from .config import PeftConfig
---> 31 from .mapping import MODEL_TYPE_TO_PEFT_MODEL_MAPPING
     32 from .peft_model import (
     33     PeftModel,
     34     PeftModelForCausalLM,
   (...)
     39     PeftModelForTokenClassification,
     40 )
     43 class _BaseAutoPeftModel:

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\peft\mapping.py:23
     20 import torch
     22 from .config import PeftConfig
---> 23 from .peft_model import (
     24     PeftModel,
     25     PeftModelForCausalLM,
     26     PeftModelForFeatureExtraction,
     27     PeftModelForQuestionAnswering,
     28     PeftModelForSeq2SeqLM,
     29     PeftModelForSequenceClassification,
     30     PeftModelForTokenClassification,
     31 )
     32 from .tuners import (
     33     AdaLoraConfig,
     34     AdaLoraModel,
   (...)
     42     PromptTuningConfig,
     43 )
     44 from .utils import _prepare_prompt_learning_config

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\peft\peft_model.py:38
     36 from . import __version__
     37 from .config import PeftConfig
---> 38 from .tuners import (
     39     AdaLoraModel,
     40     AdaptionPromptModel,
     41     IA3Model,
     42     LoraModel,
     43     PrefixEncoder,
     44     PromptEmbedding,
     45     PromptEncoder,
     46 )
     47 from .utils import (
     48     SAFETENSORS_WEIGHTS_NAME,
     49     TRANSFORMERS_MODELS_TO_PREFIX_TUNING_POSTPROCESS_MAPPING,
   (...)
     62     shift_tokens_right,
     63 )
     66 PEFT_TYPE_TO_MODEL_MAPPING = {
     67     PeftType.LORA: LoraModel,
     68     PeftType.PROMPT_TUNING: PromptEmbedding,
   (...)
     73     PeftType.IA3: IA3Model,
     74 }

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\peft\tuners\__init__.py:21
      1 # flake8: noqa
      2 # There's no way to ignore "F401 '...' imported but unused" warnings in this
      3 # module, but to preserve other warnings. So, don't check this module at all
   (...)
     17 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     18 # limitations under the License.
     20 from .adaption_prompt import AdaptionPromptConfig, AdaptionPromptModel
---> 21 from .lora import LoraConfig, LoraModel
     22 from .ia3 import IA3Config, IA3Model
     23 from .adalora import AdaLoraConfig, AdaLoraModel

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\peft\tuners\lora.py:45
     41 from .tuners_utils import BaseTuner, BaseTunerLayer
     44 if is_bnb_available():
---> 45     import bitsandbytes as bnb
     48 @dataclass
     49 class LoraConfig(PeftConfig):
     50     """
     51     This is the configuration class to store the configuration of a [`LoraModel`].
     52 
   (...)
     72             pattern is not in the common layers pattern.
     73     """

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\__init__.py:5
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. 
      2 #   
      3 # This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the 
      4 # LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
----> 5 from .optim import adam
      6 from .nn import modules
      7 print('='*30 + 'WARNING: DEPRECATED!' + '='*30)

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\optim\__init__.py:5
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. 
      2 #   
      3 # This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the 
      4 # LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
----> 5 from .adam import Adam, Adam8bit, Adam32bit
      6 from .adamw import AdamW, AdamW8bit, AdamW32bit
      7 from .sgd import SGD, SGD8bit, SGD32bit

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\optim\adam.py:11
      9 import torch
     10 import torch.distributed as dist
---> 11 from bitsandbytes.optim.optimizer import Optimizer2State
     12 import bitsandbytes.functional as F
     14 class Adam(Optimizer2State):

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\optim\optimizer.py:6
      1 # Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates. 
      2 #   
      3 # This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the 
      4 # LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
      5 import torch
----> 6 import bitsandbytes.functional as F
      8 from copy import deepcopy
      9 from itertools import chain

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\functional.py:13
     10 from torch import Tensor
     11 from typing import Tuple
---> 13 lib = ct.cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/libbitsandbytes.so')
     14 name2qmap = {}
     16 ''' C FUNCTIONS FOR OPTIMIZERS '''

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py:454, in LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(self, name)
    453 def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 454     return self._dlltype(name)

File c:\Users\georg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py:376, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    373 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
    375 if handle is None:
--> 376     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    377 else:
    378     self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```